About the conditional expectation
Given 3 random variables X,Y,Z is the following relation correct:
\begin{equation}
E_{z} \left ( \int g(x|z) dx \right)=E_{z} \left (E_{y}\left (\int g(x|y,z) dx \right) \right)
\end{equation}
My attempt:
given the low of total expectation $E_{z}(Z)=E_{y}(E_{z}(Z|Y))$ I can write
\begin{equation}
E_{z} \left ( \int g(x|z) dx \right)=E_{y} \left (E_{z}\left (\int g(x|y,z) dx \right) \right)=E_{z} \left (E_{y}\left (\int g(x|y,z) dx \right) \right)
\end{equation}
Is this correct? Shouldn't I use $E_{y|z}$ notation instead of $E_{y}$ in the  rightmost term of the expression above?
